# Script got caught in loop for 3-5 times and then stop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working on App script for my project. I am very new at all programming languages. I have been having the problem with a specific section of code that it run in loop for 3-5 times then stop by itself. The whole code is

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function Test() {
    autofill();
    replace();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
    var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastColumn)
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];

        var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
        var service = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 11).getValue();
        if (service === 0) {
            filterBTC();
            codeBTC();
        } else {
            var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
            spreadsheet.getRange('K1').activate();
            var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
                .setHiddenValues(['0'])
                .build();
            spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(11, criteria);
            spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
            spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(2, true);
            spreadsheet.getRange('B3').activate();
            spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('B3:B561'),
                SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.ALTERNATE_SERIES);
            spreadsheet.getRange('B3:B561').activate();
            SendOrder();
            removefilters();
        }
    }
}
```

The section that got stuck in loop is

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('K1').activate();
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setHiddenValues(['0'])
    .build();
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(11, criteria);
spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(2, true);
spreadsheet.getRange('B3').activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('B3:B561'),
    SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.ALTERNATE_SERIES);
spreadsheet.getRange('B3:B561').activate();
SendOrder();
removefilters();
```

Please help, I've been trying to finish this project for almost a week now.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adding this line inside the first line of your loop `console.log(data.length)`. Then inspect in the console what values you are getting back.

Comment: What is the objective of the script? It looks like you are filling down and then looking at the result...should you be manipulating with the script itself? Any context would be helpful in providing answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are very new programmer first things you should learn is how to debug your code and run script by steps and see how every variable/object changing instead of making thousands of Logs